# use of LIKE and GREATER THAN clause together

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-like

I have one question which is like "Use LIKE( with % symbol) clause to select whose SALARY greater than 12000" I have tried one solution and it is working but test cases are not passed given below is the solution I tried

```
SELECT * FROM NAMES
where Salary > 12000 AND Name LIKE '%';
```

anyone have another solution for this can help me

Comment: Normally you would do -> `select * from employee where (salary - 12000) >= 0` ... Using `LIKE` keyword usage is weird in this case not to mention wrong when you look into the ANSi/iSO SQL standards where this is not allowed as the `sql` tag is also here.. But SQLite does a implict datatype casting as `LIKE` is meant to be used on string datatypes

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a straight comparison of `12000` using the `LIKE` operator (I think), but you can do it for the difference `salary - 12000`:

```
select * from employee
where salary - 12000 not like '-%'
```

If the salary is smaller than `12000` then `salary - 12000` will be negative, meaning will start with `-`.
For the case that the salary is exactly `12000` you can add:

```
and salary not like '0'
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hXPir6fCgPBFnj8A13KZUA/1).

Comment: The requirement is to use LIKE. This is how I understand the question.

Comment: *Use LIKE( with % symbol) clause to select whose SALARY greater than 12000*

Comment: nevermind need more coffee i am giving comments to which it seams a homework based question here which has special requirements..   ..